How to verify which version of lightroom generated a catalog (.lrcat file)?
I formatted my PC and reinstalled Lightroom, but when I try to open my catalog I get the error "Catalog name X cannot be opened because it is too new to be used by this version of Lightroom".
Is there a way to know which version of Lightroom generated this catalog?
If I install the latest version of Lightroom, is it guaranteed that I will be able to open this catalog regardless of which version it is from?

I'm not a Lightroom user but it looks like there's some info in their FAQ which may answer at least some of your questions.

I am not Adobe developer so I can't tell you exactly where LR check the version. But found in catalog file few records like:
/tromeo/tf/tiso/tninov/tphotoshop/tcanon/tNNNNNNNNN/twindows/tiii/t0/t13.5.1/t9/tclassic/t//tsec/tmm/t5d/t24/tadobe/teos/tmark/t100/tlightroom/t1/200/t4

where is mentioned my version: 13.5.1
Also I found the version of RAW engine, incorporated in LR:
NNNNN-NNNNN-NNNN<snip>Adobe_CrsVersion16.3.0B!

In my case this is 16.3.0
About update, I can't be 100% sure but following Adobe practice update to last version with 95% probability will make your LR open the catalog in question. If the version of LR is too new will ask you to update the catalog to match the version.
P.S. The way I use to get these strings is:

Get this software (from sysinternals). It "extract" only readable strings from binary file

Open cmd

go to the directory where my LR library is
cd \photo\libraries\tmp

Exec this command:
\path\to\strings tmp-v13-3.lrcat|findstr /i classic

Browse the result to find something meaning

Exec command
\path\to\strings tmp-v13-3.lrcat|findstr /i crsver

again browse the result


I use UNIX/Linux tools but the idea and commands are pretty close.

Thanks for your reply @Romeo, but how did you find these records? My .lrcat file is binary and I couldn't find a way to search for records in it. I couldn't even open it in Netbeans.

@Goblin, will add it in my answer.
